# ошибка при создании экземпляра класса унаследованного от QSyntaxHighlighter

Tags: qt

Наследую класс от `QSyntaxHighlighter`, переопределяю метод `highlightBlock(const QString&)`, но при создании экземпляра и передаче в конструктор `QTextEdit::document()`, при запуске приложения выскакивает следующая ошибка:

```
Debug error
Program: C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Cored.dll
Module: 5.8.0
File: global\Qglobal.cpp
Line: 3070

ASSERT: "uint(i) < uint(size())" in file
```

Делаю все как написано в книге но выскакивает ошибка, 
помогите пожалуйста разобраться почему.

Comment: Вы бы код класса показали, а то все телепаты вымерли

Comment: class Hilight:public QSyntaxHighlighter
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int state;
    int pos_open;
    int pos_closed;
    int start;
    int end;
    int index;
    bool indic;
    QStringList list;
public:
    Hilight(QTextDocument* wig=0);
protected:
    virtual void highlightBlock(const QString& str);
private:
    bool is_complicated_comment_open(const QString& str);
    bool is_complicated_comment_closed(const QString& str);
    bool is_simple_comment(const QString& str);
    bool is_string(const QString& str);
    void highlight(const QString& str,int start,int end);
};

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него код, не надо добавлять код в комментарии

Comment: Это  header файл.

Comment: А вот реализация конструктора:
Hilight::Hilight(QTextDocument* par/*=0*/):QSyntaxHighlighter(par)
{
    state=0;
    pos_open=0;
    pos_closed=0;
    start=0;
    end=0;
    index=0;
    indic=0;
    list<<"bool"<<"int"<<"double"<<"float"<<"short"<<"char"
       <<"foreach"<<"for"<<"if"<<"else"<<"try"<<"catch"
      <<"true"<<"false"<<"break"<<"continue"<<"return"
     <<"delete"<<"new"<<"mutable"<<"this"<<"struct"<<"class"<<"union"
    <<"private"<<"public"<<"protected"<<"virtual"<<"const"<<"switch";
}